# Ambiguous Reference to Member Fix in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm using Firebase on Swift and I am trying to bypass this error:

> ambiguous reference to member 'database()'

I'm following some code on youtube to get ready for my project and I see there have been changes since then and I'm not too sure if they also changed that one. Here's my code.

```
func name(state: String){
    let ref = Database.database.reference() //This generates the error
    let post : [String: AnyObject] = ["state": state as AnyObject]
    ref.child("name").setValue(post)
}
```

Thanks

SN: I've imported Firebase and FirebaseDatabase already
Edit: Apparently, I couldn't just type it in and had to wait until it was recommended. I'll keep this question up in hopes someone will find their answer quicker than I did.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize `database` with `()`, so use this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
```